If the graded module is finitely generated then the filtration is good
Suppose $A$ is a unital Noetherian ring with an ideal $\mathfrak{q}$. Provide $A$ with its $\mathfrak{q}$-adic filtration. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module with descending filtration $(M_n)$ such that $\mathfrak{q}M_n\subset M_{n+1}$. Define now $\bar M=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0} M_n$. Then $\bar M$ is naturally a $\bar A$-module. We wish to show that if $\bar M$ is finitely generated then the filtration on $M$ is $\mathfrak{q}$-good, meaning that $M_{n+1}=\mathfrak{q}M_n$ for sufficiently large $n$.
Since $\bar M$ is finitely generated, it is generated by elements of degree at most $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Replace these generators by their homogeneous parts if they are not homogeneous. We have $\mathfrak{q}M_m\subset M_{m+1}$ by definition. How to show that $M_{m+1}\subset \mathfrak{q}M_m$? Both submodules $M_m$ and $M_{m+1}$ are finitely generated since $M$ is finitely generated and $A$ is Noetherian. Moreover the generators of $M_m$ also generated $M_{m+1}$ since $M_{m+1}\subset M_m$.
Now if we pick an element $x$ from $M_{n+1}$ we can express it as $\sum_{\lambda\in L} a_\lambda m_\lambda$. If we can show that each $a_\lambda$ can be replaced by an element in $\mathfrak{q}^{m+1-\mathrm{deg}(m_\lambda)}$ then we are done. This is easy if the highest degree summand in the expansion of $a_\lambda$ is greater than $m+1-\mathrm{deg}(m_\lambda)$ but I can't figure out how to proceed if not.
